# Can I use api gateway with route53 to support customer domain for Appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-appsync

I am building application deployed to Appsync in AWS. And appsync doesn't support custom domain so that I have to choose a workaround.

I have read some doc and all of them mention to use cloudfront. I wonder whether I can use API gateways instead of cloudfront. For me, I don't want to use any CDN for my backend (even I know I can disable cache).

And I'd like to support subscription over websocket. Does it work with api gateway?

Answer (score 0):

We can setup proxy from Api Gateway both HTTP and REST. Considering this is just proxy and no customizations, we can go with cheaper option of HTTP API.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-http.html) is the documentation.
Step by Step:

- Create a HTTP Api
- Add a route for `/{proxy+}` with ANY method.
- Add an integration to ANY method pointing to appsync api suffixing with {proxy} `https://kkkkabcd1efgxyzeabcdefg4.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{proxy}`
- Route53 to point to Api Gateway.

Comment: Does it support websocket? The doc doesn't mention whether websocket is supported